Lock Free Queue, any problems with this
QueryWorker is a Class and QueryWorker.Next is a QueryWorker Field.
This will Enqueue the Writer and put it last in line.
Returns true if you are the first in line.
Do you see any problems with this, this is only for enqueue, the pop part is a single consumer and therefore do not need locking.
 internal bool TryStartWriting(QueryWorker Writer)
        {
            QueryWorker? Last;

            do
            {
                Last = WriterQueueHead;

                while (Last is null)
                {
                    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref WriterQueueHead, Writer, null) is null)
                        return true;

                    Last = WriterQueueHead;
                }

                while (Last.Next is not null)
                    Last = Last.Next;

            } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Last.Next, Writer, null) is not null);

            WriterQueueHead = Writer;
            return false;
        }


What if there’s one writer in the queue, then the consumer dequeues it while another one is being added, between while (Last.Next is not null) and the outer loop condition?

Yeah, the single consumer has to do some race condition check, but that should not be a problem

I think this is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

@AntonChristiansen just for fun, can we have the Pop method?

It's perhaps fine on x86 and probably not on ARM, but not being super familiar with the relevant stack of memory models, I don't want to answer authoritatively. Why are you rolling your own queue?

@DavidEisenstat: What does x86 vs. ARM have to do with this?

@DavidEisenstat Why would it not be fine, care to elaborate

@Ry- TSO versus not.

When I need a linked MPSC queue, I usually use the classic "make a queue out of 2 stacks" solution.  The input stack is lock-free, and the output stack is single-threaded.

@MattTimmermans Its a Queue not a stack, the Writer.Next will be set on the next writer as this one is set to WriterQueueHead at the end.

Right... but if you start with an empty queue and call tryStartWriting twice, how does the reader find the first item written.  It appears that there would be no pointer to it anywhere.

You seem to be heading toward this: https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf
